# Cannot update Logitech Unifying Receiver (version of org.freedesktop.fwupd incorrect: failed predicate [0.9.2 ge 0.8.1])

Tags: logitech-unifying, fwupd

There's security update for the Logitech Unifying Receiver (see Screenshot).

[image: Ubuntu Software Screenshot]

Clicking the button does nothing.

I came across this post https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/109038/logitech-unifying-receiver-security-update/
Updating via command line doesn't work either

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr update
Downloading RQR12.07_B0029 for Unifying [runtime]...
Updating RQR12.07_B0029 on Unifying [runtime]...
Decompressing…         
version of org.freedesktop.fwupd incorrect: failed predicate [0.9.2 ge 0.8.1]
```

The only Google result for the error message is https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2017/05/22/updating-logitech-hardware-on-linux/ . But the comment mentioning it doesn't look resolved.

So how do I install the update? Correct me if I'm wrong, but `0.9.2` is greater than or equal `0.8.1` which means the predicate check is just broken?

```
$ sudo apt-get -s upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: device can not be used during update ? Download the .deb, shut down, remove hardware, reboot and either update or install the .deb . Not really sure what hardware that is so not sure what ubuntu package that is exactly.

Comment: You may need to file a bug report against the ubutnu package.

Comment: in a terminal type `sudo apt-get -s upgrade` and post the output.

Comment: Added the output of `sudo apt-get -s upgrade`. It is a firmware update, hence removing the hardware does not work as it needs to be plugged in to update the firmware. Also removing the hardware removes the update (fwup depetects the connected hardware).

Comment: Does it still show as an available update in software center ? You may need to file a bug report against fwupdmgr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/issues/253#issuecomment-329755909) with fwupd. You need fwudp 0.9.2 or greater to update. Ubuntu 17.04 ships with 0.8.1. One solution is to use a live USB of a distribution such as Xubuntu 17.10 b1 which has a more recent version in its repositories. Since it is a firmware upgrade you can use the other distro to update the Unifying Receiver and then boot back into your normal system.

- get a bootable USB disk with a distro containing a current version (I went with Xubuntu 17.10 b1, which currently has fwupd `0.9.7`). Note that you probably want a 64-bit version of the OS - 32-bit fwupd segfaults if device is plugged in.
- boot the live distro
- plug in the receiver
- `apt update`
- `apt install fwupd`
- edit `/etc/fwupd/remotes.d/lvfs-testing.conf` - change `Enabled=false` to `Enabled=true`
- `fwupdmgr refresh && fwupdmgr update`

Source: https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/issues/253#issuecomment-329755909

Comment: Worked ok here  using my 17.10 install. Maybe consider mentioning user has to run a command to get it. (unless it shows up in software manager, didn't here.) I used `sudo fwupdmgr update`

Comment: `fwupdmgr refresh && fwupdmgr update` was enough for me on 20.04

Answer (score 2):

I only did a simple search for `fwupd` from Ubuntu software and installed `fw-uefi-tools` and then  `fwupd`.
This solved the problem (for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

(thanks to Chai T. Rex and zx485)

Comment: I only installed `fwupd` (v 1.1.4) from Ubuntu Software and the problem was immediately fixed on 16.04. There was no need for me install `fw-uefi-tools`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo fwupdmgr update; sleep 3; sudo fwupdmgr update;
```

I lifted the line from [here](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/1164#issuecomment-529130782).

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I was able to get past this by following the last two steps of Prinzhorn's answer on my running machine with no extra live CD boot.  I did not verify that the edit step is strictly necessary, I just did it and it worked.

- edit `/etc/fwupd/remotes.d/lvfs-testing.conf` - change `Enabled=false` to `Enabled=true`
- `fwupdmgr refresh && fwupdmgr update`