# Can't upgrade Logitech unify Firmware using fwupd

Tags: logitech-unifying, fwupd

When I run the command to update the firmware it states to manually be put in update mode. I've searched for an explanation but can't find anything that helps.

```
# fwupdmgr -v update
Downloading RQR12.07_B0029 for Unifying [runtime]...
Updating RQR12.07_B0029 on Unifying [runtime]...
Decompressing…         
Device Unifying [runtime] needs to manually be put in update mode
```

Output from *fwupdmgr get-devices*:

```
Unifying [runtime]
  Guid:                 9d131a0c-a606-580f-8eda-80587250b8d6
  UniqueID:             com.logitech.Unifying.RQR12.firmware
  DeviceID:             usb:00:01
  Description:          <p>A Unifying receiver allows you to connect multiple compatible keyboards and mice to a laptop or desktop computer with a single USB receiver. Updating the firmware on your Unifying receiver improves performance, adds new features and fixes security issues.</p>
  Plugin:               unifying
  Flags:                allow-online|supported|needs-bootloader
  DeviceVendor:         Logitech
  Version:              003.000.12003
  VersionBootloader:    BL.0aa.0aa
  Created:              2018-05-04
  AppstreamId:          com.logitech.Unifying.RQR12.firmware
  Summary:              Firmware for the Logitech Unifying receiver
  UpdateDescription:    <p>This release addresses an unencrypted keystroke injection issue known as Bastille security issue #11. The vulnerability is complex to replicate and would require a hacker to be physically close to a target.</p>
  UpdateVersion:        RQR12.07_B0029
  UpdateHash:           d0d33e760ab6eeed6f11b9f9bd7e83820b29e970
  UpdateChecksumKind:   sha1
  License:              Proprietary
  UpdateUri:            https://fwupd.org/downloads/938fec082652c603a1cdafde7cd25d76baadc70d-Logitech-Unifying-RQR12.07_B0029.cab
  UrlHomepage:          http://support.logitech.com/en-us/software/unifying
  Vendor:               Logitech
  Trusted:              none
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update for Ubuntu 22.04**, see below:

I tested all (probably most) of the solutions that are online. And the solution that worked (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Live) is the following:

1. Remove the `apt` version of `fwupd` with

   ```
    sudo apt remove fwupd
   ```

   Because the current repository version of Ubuntu 18.04 seems to be

   > client version: 1.0.9
   > checkout info:  1.0.9

   This is a problem, because this version yields the following error:

   > **cannot handle firmware requirement not-child**
2. Replace it with the `snap` version of `fwupd` which also (maybe) installs `snap`, too.

   ```
    sudo snap install fwupd --classic
   ```

   The current `snap` version on the other hand provides a newer version which works without this complication. Its version is (as of July 2019)

   > client version: 1.2.10
   > checkout info:  1.2.10

   As of June 2020, the following is valid

   > client version: 1.4.3
   > daemon version: 1.4.3
3. With this current version, execute

   ```
    fwupdmgr refresh
   ```
4. And finally, execute the update

   ```
    fwupdmgr update
   ```
5. Now test the version with

   ```
    fwupdmgr get-devices | grep -A30 "Unifying Receiver" | grep -i "version:"
   ```

   Its output should be (as of 15th May 2021):

   > Current version:     RQR12.10_B0032

---

Tested again on **Ubuntu 22.04**. No need to install the snap, because it will probably break dependencies due to version mismatch

> Unsupported daemon version 1.8.1, client version is 1.7.5

22.04 has already installed version 1.7.5 which should be fine. Run only

```
fwupdmgr refresh
fwupdmgr update
```

and check with

```
fwupdmgr get-devices | grep -A30 "Unifying Receiver" | grep -i "version:"
```

the versions, as of 2022-06-18, are

```
 Current version:    RQR24.10_B0036
 Bootloader Version: BOT03.00_B0006
 Current version:    01.01A01
```

---

Finally, to po pair devices via GUI, you can use `solaar` from the universe repository

```
sudo apt-get install solaar-gnome3
```

Run `solaar`.

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo` with `fwupdmgr` when updating firmware for Unifying Receiver.

Comment: Look at the end of the page for reference [here](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/docs/users)

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04. I had to do `sudo updatedb` before running step 3

Comment: This also fixes the "Failed to obtain auth" errors I got on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/issues/500) the problem is most likely caused by the version of fwupd being too old and no longer supported. The fix, suggested both on that issue and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/958771) is to boot from a live media with a newer version of fwupd and to upgrade using that version. Please see the latter answer for details on how to do that.

[Later Edit]: Even though I tried the above with Ubuntu 18.04 and it updated successfully, after booting back to Ubuntu 16.04 the update was still showing up. I eventually updated the firmware via a Windows machine and the software from [here](https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D531000058b3B7CAI/logitech-response-to-research-findings). I am not certain that that is the latest version (as the software did not report the firmware version) but the Ubuntu update did disappear afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

For me these commands worked

```
   sudo apt remove fwupd

   sudo snap install fwupd --classic

   sudo fwupdmgr refresh

   fwupdmgr update

   sudo fwupdmgr -v update (mouse on)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of another [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161043/829702)

Answer (score 0):

Following [JayDin's](https://askubuntu.com/users/553502/jaydin) comment I confirm the simpliest solution on 16.04 (XFCE) is:

1. Open *Ubuntu Software* and search for `fwupd`
2. Install only `fwupd` (no need for `fw-uefi-tools`)

This will upgrade the daemon version which is sufficent to complete the job.
Run `fwupdmgr --version` to check:

`# fwupdmgr --version
client version: 0.8.3
daemon version: 1.2.10`

Comment: That way you have both apt version and snap version of the software installed. Use `fwupd.fwupdmgr` for the snap version.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo fwupdmgr -v update` with mouse off and it's done.

This worked on 5.3.0-19-generic #20-Ubuntu.