# Can Software Center see updates from the snap version of fwupd?

Tags: software-center, snap, fwupd

As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161043/23660), I have uninstalled `fwupd` and replaced it with the snap version. This made it possible to update Unifying peripherals, but now I wonder about the following.:

I am used to getting regular messages from Ubuntu Software Center, that firmware updates are available.
Will I still be getting these messages now that `fwupd` lives in a snap? 
Can the Ubuntu Software Center see the service that runs from the snap properly?

Answer (score 1):

I just got the answer this morning, when I booted with another Unifying receiver inserted. It works without any issues.