# fwupd won't update Unifying receiver firmware

Tags: usb, updates, firmware, logitech-unifying, fwupd

LVFS says there is a firmware update for my Logitech Unifying Receiver, RQR12.10_B0032 uploaded 2019-9-19 and rated high urgency.

Gnome Software does not find any firmware updates but running `fwupdmgr get-devices` returns:

```
Unifying Receiver
  DeviceId:             d6f6ce27dc66c459a4392a8414cfb54e9d15c3be
  Guid:                 9d131a0c-a606-580f-8eda-80587250b8d6
  Guid:                 279ed287-3607-549e-bacc-f873bb9838c4
  Summary:              A miniaturised USB wireless receiver
  Plugin:               unifying
  Flags:                updatable|supported|registered
  Vendor:               Logitech
  VendorId:             USB:0x046D
  Version:              RQR12.09_B0030
  VersionBootloader:    BOT01.04_B0016
  VersionFormat:        plain
  Icon:                 preferences-desktop-keyboard
  InstallDuration:      7
  Created:              2019-11-03
```

I believe I saw firmware version RQR12.09_B0030 firmware discussed in a 2017 thread somewhere.

Running either `fwupdmgr get-updates` or `fwpudmgr update` returns:

```
No releases found for device: Not compatible with bootloader version:              failed predicate [BOT01.0[0-3]_* regex BOT01.04_B0016]
```

Operating system is Ubuntu 19.10. I do not understand what bootloader is referenced in the message.

In the LVFS Security notes for RQR12.10_B0032 it states, "Firmware cannot be verified after flashing." Does this mean the firmware upgrade won't show up even if it has occurred?

I've been using linux for a dozen years. I am comfortable using the Terminal if instructions are clear. If there is a recommended cure, please keep it simple for me.

PS: I have reviewed the May 2018 thread labeled [Can't upgrade Logitech unify Firmware using fwupd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031871/cant-upgrade-logitech-unify-firmware-using-fwupd/1161043)
but my scenario seems very different in every way.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an official workaround https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/LVFS-Triaged-Issue:-Logitech-Restart-Failure

so I updated it using following script (cannot do that manually because after the first fail mouse and keyboard disconnects)

```
#!/bin/bash

fwupdmgr update
sleep 5
fwupdmgr update
```